# DICOM Header parsing using pixelMed

Tags: java, dicom, pixelmed

Am trying to read DICOM Header using pixelMed Library. Here's the code snippet.

```
try {
    DicomInputStream dis = new DicomInputStream
                             (new ByteArrayInputStream(dicomHeaderBytes));
    AttributeList attributeList = new AttributeList();
    attributeList.setDecompressPixelData(false);
    attributeList.read(dis);
    attributeList.removeUnsafePrivateAttributes();
    /* Iterating over attribute List */
    for(Map.Entry<AttributeTag,Attribute> entry : attributeList.entrySet()){
            AttributeTag key = entry.getKey();
            Attribute value = entry.getValue();
            String vr = value.getVRAsString();
            String description = "";
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error("Exception occurred", e);
}
```

How to read the description of dicom tags.
Ex: For tag: 0008,0020, the description should be "Study Date".

Comment: implementation language?

Comment: Java is being used here.

Comment: My question got downvoted. I'm wondering if something's wrong?

Comment: I edited in the Java tag, but there is still a lot of room for improvement. Can you show your own attempt at fetching the name of that attribute? Have you looked the documentation for something equivalent to the standard data dictionary? Also, _"please suggest me a different library [...]"_ is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should not be asking for such a recommendation.

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=dicom+header+tags

Comment: Was trying to get description programmatically using the AttributeTag and Attribute Value

Answer (score 1):

Using 'DicomDictionary' class from pixelMed, I was able to retrieve the tag description by passing AttributeTag.

```
String tagDescription = dicomDictionary.getFullNameFromTag(new AttributeTag(int, int));
```